# If $\partial X=\{(0,0)\}$ then $X=\mathbb{R}^2-\{(0,0)\}$

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

The following proposition is false

Let $X$ be a subset of $\mathbb{R}$ such that $X$ is open and
$$
\partial X=\{0\}
$$
then $X=\mathbb{R}-\{0\}$. For example $X=]-\infty,0[$.

---

But the following proposition is true?

Let $X$ be a subset of $\mathbb{R}^2$ such that $X$ is open and
$$
\partial X=\{(0,0)\}
$$
then $X=\mathbb{R}^2-\{(0,0)\}$.

$\partial X$: Boundary of $X$

Any hint would be appreciated

Comment: If $X\subset\Bbb R$, how can $\partial X$ be equal to $\{(0,0)\}$?

Comment: Do you see why $X$ is both closed and open as a subset of $\Bbb R^2 \setminus \{(0, 0)\}$ (and how to use this...)? This is the key difference between dimension 1 and higher dimensions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is true in great generality.

Suppose $Y$ is a topological space and $X\subset Y$ is a not empty open subspace.
The closure of $X$ is $\overline{X}=X\cup\partial X$, where the union is disjoint being $X$ open.
Call $Z=Y-\partial X$ then
$$X\cap Z=X=\overline{X}\cap Z.$$
Therefore $X$ is both closed and open as a subspace of $Z$, we used no hypothesis except $X$ open.

If we now suppose $Z$ connected we get $X=Z$.